# Can you suppress Smart GWT's TreeGrid from showing icons when there is only 1 element?

Tags: smartgwt

I am using Smart GWT 4. I have data to present that may or may not have children. I decided to display this information in a TreeGrid. It looks fine when there are children to display but in the cases where a data element does not have children there is an image of a circle with a dot where the plus sign would be if there were children. Is there anyway to suppress this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a method `setShowOpener(boolean)` on the `TreeGrid` that allows you to turn on/off.